# How to fill an array in a mongoose schema after creating?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I have the following two schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  provider: String,
  username: String,
  ...
  categories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}],
  ...
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  adultOnly: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  ...
});

export default mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

Now whenever i create a new user, i want to autofill his categories with all existing categories. Dependig on his age he might not get assigned to the adultOnly categories.

How do i do that? I tried it like that:

```
var newUser = new User(req.body);
  ...
  newUser.saveAsync()
    .spread(function(user) {


  Category.findAsync({}, '_id', function(err, categories) {
    if (!err){

      var size = categories.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        user.categories.push(categories[i]._id);
      }

    } else {throw err;}
  });

  ...

 })
 .catch(validationError(res));
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps :

```
var newUser = new User(req.body);
...
newUser.saveAsync()
.spread(function(user) {
  Category.find({}, {'_id': 1}, function(err, categories) {
    if (!err){
      /*var size = categories.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        user.categories.push(categories[i]._id);
      }*/
      user.categories = [];
      user.categories = categories;
    } else {throw err;}
  });
...
})
.catch(validationError(res));
```